# mplayer -vo caca with geometry

Tags: console, video, framebuffer, mplayer, window-geometry

This `-geometry 256x144+1095+600` work to show video in rigth bottom:

```
mplayer -ontop -noborder -geometry 256x144+1095+600 -loop 0 -idle -fixed-vo -msglevel all=-1 2>/dev/null video.mp4
```

[image]

But this one (`-vo caca`) always stay in same position with same width and height regardless of `-geometry any_value`:

```
mplayer -vo caca -ontop -noborder -geometry 256x144+1095+600 -loop 0 -idle -fixed-vo -msglevel all=-1 2>/dev/null video.mp4
```

[image]

My ultimate goal is display it in virtual console, so i wanted to know the equivalent format of `-geometry` for `-vo caca`. (It could be nice to know `-vo fbdev` too :)

Answer (score 1):

Not all videodrivers in mplayer support the option -geometry.

I solved it for me with xfce4-terminal.

I had to export a Variable in .bashrc

`CACA_DRIVER=ncurses
export CACA_DRIVER`

I start mplayer `xfce4-terminal --geometry=+0+0  --hide-menubar  --hide-toolbar  --hide-borders -e "mplayer -vo caca -quiet Avatar.mp4" &`

xfce4-terminal starts so left side top.

[image] Is this something you are looking for?

Sorry, I can not better explain in englisch.

Bahamut

Comment: I'm not sure why but it doesn't play in virtual konsole (Ctrl+Shift+N). And i can't make it always-on-top on gnome(I know it's not important because what's the point i use `-vo caca` while i already can access gnome)

Comment: the Option -vo fbdev supported -geometry.  It depends on the Modul for your graphics. `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2 ` But you mußt have the device /dev/fb0 or you get this message `Can't open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
` and you hear only audio-stream. I have only a german Link as source.